# ВНЖ: какого рода эта аббревиатура?

Tags: аббревиатуры

*Вид на жительство*. Не могу понять, опорное слово тут *вид* или *жительство*? Смысловым словом, вроде, является *жительство*. А опорным — *вид*. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не сталкивался с подобной аббревиатурой. Если уж делать что-то подобное, то ВнЖ.

Понятие "опорного слова" здесь тоже как-то ни к селу, ни к городу. Грамматический род аббревиатуры определяет либо внешний её вид (ВУЗ - м, ОСАГО - ср. и проч.), либо, что чаще для менее ходовых аббревиатур и аббревиатур, не содержащих гласных - грамматический род существительного в именительном падеже (тут - "вид"). 
Таким образом, по обоим критериям ВнЖ будет мужского рода. Но, повторюсь, аббревиатура Ваша совсем не из числа ходовых.

Не путайте только с ПМЖ, оно среднего рода по слову "место", да и "окончание" "-же" напоминает драже или бланманже.

Comment: Все пишут "ВНЖ", а не "ВнЖ". С тем же успехом можно писать не "ООО", а "Ооо" или "ооо" в зависимости от места в предложении.

Comment: @gecube, я желаю вам "того же успеха" в освоении русского языка.
При чем тут "место в предложении№ всех ваших ооо, Ооо и ООО (из которых аерно только последнее) я, простите, не понимаю. 

А вообще-то я сказал, что подобная аббревиатыра мне не знакома в принципе. И словарями, кстати, не фиксируется.

Comment: @tmp, Вы видимо меня не поняли. Почему Вы буквы "н" в "ВнЖ" написали строчной? В других ведь аббревиатурах ничего подобного нет. Ну, я и сказал, что с тем же успехом можно "ООО" писать по-разному (хотя это и неправильно, но я и не говорил, что это правильно делать)

Comment: В аббревиатурах служебные слова (предлоги и союзы) либо опускаются либо пишутся пишутся строчными.
Cравните хотя бы со\ловарно-фиксируемые: СНиП, КЗоТ, МиГ и проч.  
И никакого успеха.

Подробнее есть [тут][1], при желании найдете и более авторитетные источники, мне просто сейчас недосуг.

[1]: http://line2005.narod.ru/redaktor.htm

Comment: Спасибо!!))) Ценю Вашу помощь. И всех, кто старался помочь.

Comment: @roger, ООО — это «общество с ограниченной ответственностью». Все три «О» образованы от существительных, потому и заглавные.

Answer (score 3):

Род инициальных аббревиатур (они читаются, произносятся по названиям букв, например, АПН читается как а-пэ-эн) диктуется родом опорного слова словосочетания, сократившегося в аббревиатуру. В Вашем случае опорное слово "вид" м. р., значит и аббревиатура относится к мужскому роду.

Comment: Соан, а что такое "опорное слово" в данном случае?
Определение.
Я сталкивался с подобным понятием только при переводк и в теории текста. Видимо, я тут чего-то недопонимаю - и напрасно оговорил ТС.

"Главное слово" я бы еще понял.

Comment: Странно, что Вы такого словосочетания не знаете. Не мною оно придумано. Надеюсь, что справочник по грамматике Д. Розенталя для Вас авторитетный и ресурс "Грамота.ру". См. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=gender, пункт 2.

Answer (score 2):

Главным словом в словосочетании *"вид на жительство"* является *"вид"*, поэтому аббревиатура  мужского рода. Именно таким образом определяется род аббревиатур.